# In .Net MVC3 how to handle server side error in JqGrid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, jqgrid

I am using JqGrid with MVC 3.

Some errors are handled in the server side code when I am trying to delete a row.

How can I pass this error message to JqGrid?

For example, In the action method:

```
[AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
public ActionResult Delete(int id) {
    Project project = dbContext.Projects.Find(id);
    dbContext.Projects.Remove(project);

    try {
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
    } catch (DbUpdateException){
        // Send the error to JqGrid
    }

    return RedirectToAction("Index");
}
```

In JqGrid:

```
$('#DataTable').        
jqGrid('navGrid', '#pager',
{ add: true, del: true, edit: true, search: false },
{ url: Url("Edit", controllerName), closeAfterEdit: true },
{ url: Url("Create", controllerName), closeAfterAdd: true },            
{ url: Url("Delete", controllerName) }
);
```

the method `URL` simply creates the URL to the action method

Comment: @archil: I have added the JqGrid code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution.

Just throw the exception from the catch block and JqGrid will catch it!

I did not expect it though!!!

Like:

```
        try {
            dbContext.SaveChanges();
        } catch (DbUpdateException){
            throw new Exception("Could not delete project.");
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
try
{
     dbContext.SaveChanges();
     return Json(true);
} 
catch (DbUpdateException)
{
     var json = new { msgkey = "Could not delete project." };
     return Json(json);
}
```